# Rickshaw Graph Dashing scss edits

Tags: coffeescript, sass, rickshaw, dashing

I'm trying to change some of the colors the scss file uses and enlarge the text of the legend.  I've edited these values in the rickshawgraph.scss file, but it remains unchanged when I launch the dashing rickshaw graph.

https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023
Here is my block of edits.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sass declarations
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$background-color:  #dc5945;

$title-color:       rgba(126, 126, 126, 0.7);
$moreinfo-color:    rgba(126, 126, 126, 0.5);
$tick-color:        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

Here is the block from the original file.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sass declarations
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$background-color:  #dc5945;

$title-color:       rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
$moreinfo-color:    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
$tick-color:        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the legend edit:

```
.rickshaw_legend {
```

and add...

```
font-size: YOURFONTSIZEpx;
```

You may also want to change the height or similar to fit by adding:

```
height: YOURHEIGHTSIZEpx;
```

I think the problem you may have with the colors is that you have left the opacity the same - rgba(255, 255, 255, **0.7**);

Make this opacity 1...

```
rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

Comment: I pretty much did that a while ago when I was having this issue and it worked.  Thanks for taking the time to reply here.